# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - SQL Server SELECT INTO Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting, sql-convert

I am sure this question has been asked in different ways but I am at my wits end for some reason.  I am performing a pretty straight forward SELECT INTO FROM statement which includes A WHERE on the date to be added but I cannot get the temporary table to create - I continually get the above error.  Tried all kinds of CONVERT/CAST etc but no luck.  The date is stored as this format in the DB: 
2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 but I have had no problem querying in other areas of the DB using '01/01/2017' for example.

SQL Code:

```
SELECT AO.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AS 'SALES_ORDER_NUMBER', 
       AO.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AS 'SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER',
       II.BILLING_DOCUMENT_NUMBER AS 'BILLING_DOCUMENT_NUMBER', 
       CASE 
            WHEN IH.SOLD_TO = '0000006070'
            THEN '66400'
            WHEN IH.SOLD_TO = '0000006075'
            THEN '66315'
            ELSE AO.BILL_TO
       END AS 'BILL_TO',
       AO.MATERIAL AS 'MATERIAL', 
       AO.SIZE_INDEX AS 'SIZE_INDEX',
       AO.REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE AS 'REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE'


INTO ##Temp_Invoiced

FROM  VW_AR_ORDER_ORIGINAL AO 

JOIN  VW_INVOICES_ITEM II ON AO.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = II.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AND AO.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = II.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER

JOIN VW_INVOICES_HEADER IH ON II.BILLING_DOCUMENT_NUMBER = IH.BILLING_DATE

WHERE AO.STOCK_CATEGORY LIKE '%1002%'

AND   AO.REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE >= '01/01/2017';
```

Comment: Perhaps it have something to do with this `II.BILLING_DOCUMENT_NUMBER = IH.BILLING_DATE`.

Comment: where exactly are you encountering the error? what line?

Comment: Try to use `2017/01/01` or `Datefromparts(2017,01,01)`

Comment: Hi and thank you - it is showing as Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 which is actually where SELECT begins. There are comments above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - you were exactly right sorry for the dummy question lol!  I am not quite an expert at knowing where to look first but all of you gurus are a huge help and next time I will make sure to look at my joins!  Best.

Comment: I got lazy and used the auto populate (and a new computer which is very sensitive).  Thanks all!  Hopefully one day soon I will be able to help others!

Comment: This is why a query should be well formated. I like separating each column into its own row for most of my queries. Guesswork gone, clarity, yes.